# Must shader uniforms be uploaded once for every VAO?

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

Must shader uniforms (like the projection matrix that does not change very often) be uploaded once per vertex array object? Or does the bound variables have nothing to do with the active VAO, and the shader are only connected with the vertex object when drawn?

(E.g. does a shader stand for its own until vertex data is sent to it via a draw command, or is it somehow bound to the vao created?)

Comment: Think of uniforms as their namesake implies, they are uniform. Vertex Arrays are used to supply data on a per-vertex basis, but uniform variables are uniform across every element of input data (e.g. vertex [VS], primitive [GS], fragment [PS]) each stage (shader) of your GLSL program works on. You set them per-program object and the value can be used in every stage attached to that program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uniforms have nothing to do with VAOs; they're completely different data. Uniforms are program object state. VAOs are entirely separate objects.

As with most state, uniform data set into a program will remain that way until you change it.